# Why is my ebike Shimano display dead?

Tags: shimano, electric-bike, battery

The bike battery is fully charged. When I plug-in the display, the screen does not come on at all.

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. You will need to add more information for us to be able to offer an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is with the system fully off and ideally with the battery removed, check the wire connections, ideally using the e-tube wire plug tool that would have come with the system (TL-EW02 or TL-EW300). If you don't have this, it can be done very carefully with pliers.

The next steps would be physically confirming the wire is plugged into the drive unit and in good condition (not squashed anywhere, as can happen), and then having a dealer plug it into the e-tube software for troubleshooting. (The software will likely have something to say about what the problem is, and providing you have the means to hook it up, doing that is much faster than taking off the cranks and drive unit covers to begin physical troubleshooting).